Two parameter differential equation solution
I am working on the paper titled "Energetic and entropic effects of bath-induced coherences" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02013)and there is a two parameter differential equation for calculating the population rates such that:
$$
\dot{P}_{+} = -4[G(ω) – G(-ω)]p_{o} – 4[2G(ω) + G(-ω)]P_{+} + 4G(ω)r  \\
\dot{P}_{o} = 4G(ω)P{+} - 4G(-ω)P_{o}
$$
However, it defines a new quantity to obtain the results such that
$$q^{\pm} = {P}_{+} + (1 \pm \sqrt{G(-ω)/G(ω)})P_{o} $$
with the corresponding eigen values
$$a^{\pm} = 4 (\pm \sqrt{G(-ω)G(ω)}-G(ω)-G(-ω)) $$
My question is, is this an approach to solve the main equantions or I am making mistake.
